# What is the reality condition for an electric field polarization?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, fourier-transform, polarization

For example in Cohen-Tannoudji's book, it's given that for a propagating electromagnetic wave, you can define your polarization to have this property (all in Fourier space):

$$E^*(k, t) = E(-k,t),$$

where $k$ is the wave vector. How is this justified?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties for properties of the Fourier transform. Intuitively, this property makes sense from a phasor diagram standpoint: for two rotating phasors to add up to a real number for all space, they must be evolving in the opposite direction ($k_1=-k_2$), and they must have the same magnitude and a canceling imaginary part ($E(k_1) = E^*(k_2)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic property of Fourier transforms.

Quoting from Cohen-Tannoudji (*Photon and atoms, introduction to QED*, beginning of section I.B.1):

> Since $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t)$ is real, it follows that $$\mathscr{E}^*(\mathbf{k}, t) = \mathscr{E}(-\mathbf{k}, t).$$

Note that $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) \leftrightarrow \mathscr{E}(\mathbf{k}, t)$ are linked by a Fourier transformation.

**If a function is real**, the complex conjugate of its Fourier transform at $\mathbf{k}$ is equal to the value of the Fourier transform at $-\mathbf{k}$.

This can be seen by looking at the Fourier transforms of the cosine and the sine functions (hint: *How do you write cosine or sine as a sum of exponentials?*), and then noting any one-dimensional real function can be represented by a sum of cosine and sine functions.

It only takes a little bit of thought to see that this property of Fourier transforms extends to higher-dimensional Fourier transforms (in this case, a three-dimensional one).

Comment: Oh, it's a general feature of a real function, no assumptions made just for electric fields. Thanks a ton ✌️